# Windsor resolve IEnumerable<IMyType>

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Via Windsor I register multiple implementation types to a single interface type :

```
public class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
  {
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
      container.Register(
        Component.For<IMyType>()
          .ImplementedBy<MyTypeClass1>()
          .Named("MyTypeClass1")
          .LifestyleTransient());

      container.Register(
        Component.For<IMyType>()
          .ImplementedBy<MyTypeClass2>()
          .Named("MyTypeClass2")
          .LifestyleTransient());
    }
  }
}
```

and I have a consuming class :

```
public class MyConsumingClass : IMyConsumingClass
  {
    private readonly IList<IMyType> _myObjects;

    public MyConsumingClass(IEnumerable<IMyType> myObjects)
    {
      _myObjects = myObjects.ToList();
    }
}
```

however at runtime I receive following exception :

```
Can't create component 'MyConsumingClass' as it has dependencies to be satisfied. 'MyConsumingClass' is waiting for the following dependencies: - 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[IMyType, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.
```

Answer (score 23):

I think you may need to add a [CollectionResolver](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md) to your container.

Try:

```
kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(kernel));
```

Answer (score 8):

I like @shenku's answer and I'd add this note as a comment, but I can't since I'm a newb. (<50 reputation).  Don't mark me as an answer! :)

When you add the sub resolver consider adding the optional parameter for allowing empty collections to resolve correctly as well.

`kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(kernel, true));`

Answer (score -1):

What should be the value of IEnumerable myObjects ?

If it is evertime the same, you can register it like this:

```
ICollection<IMyType> someCollection= new Collection<IMyType>();
// add some elements

container.Register(Component.For<IEnumerable<IMyType>>().Instance(collection));
```

If it's changed in runtime, you should resolve it like:

```
ICollection<IMyType> someCollection= new Collection<IMyType>();
// add some elements
var myConsumingClass = container.Resolve<MyConsumingClass>(new {myObjects = someCollection});
```

BTW, if this code is not inside your entry point, you should use [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) insdead of container.resolve